# Filtering Lists in a List of Lists (Python) Based on Values

Tags: python, list, loops

Hey I'm trying to write a function that only prints a list that contains no zeros in a list of lists.  Here is a sample of the list of lists I am working with:

```
[['10011.0', ' 65301.0', ' 0.085', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.03', ' 0.03', ' 0.075',
 ' 0.05', ' 0.065', ' 0.05', ' 0.05', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0'],
 ['10017.0', ' 2743.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.2', ' 0.413333', ' 0.415', ' 0.3125', ' 0.45', ' 0.46', ' 0.55'],
 ['10017.0', ' 9262.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.35', ' 0.69', ' 0.675', ' 0.8075', ' 0.8075', ' 0.5325', ' 0.785'], 
 ['10017.0', ' 29319.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0225', ' 0.06', ' 0.0575', ' 0.105', ' 0.1', ' 0.045', ' 0.0'],
 ['10017.0', ' 43562.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.0', ' 0.106667', ' 0.0925', ' 0.09', ' 0.1', ' 0.09', ' 0.1025'],
 ['10017.0', ' 43563.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 0.106667', ' 0.0925', ' 0.09', ' 0.1', ' 0.09', ' 0.1028']]
```

The code I am running is:

```
def no_zero(A):
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(2, (len(A[i])+1)):
        if '0.0' not in A[i]:
            print A[i]
            break
```

For some reason it does not filter any of the lists and prints the entire list of lists despite the conditional: "if '0.0' not in A[i]:"  I am unsure where my error is because it seems like the logic should be fairly straightforward.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you have the second `for` loop? You never use `j` anywhere.

Comment: I need it to skip the first two elements of the list.  Sorry for not clarifying that in the initial question.

Comment: Alright, but you still never use `j` anywhere in your code. You also don't want to use `len+1` as your termination point, because `A[len(A)]` never exists.

Answer (score 3):

Normally when you want to filter a list of items, we use list comprehension with the filtering condition to get a new list. So, in your case, it can be done like this

```
[c_list for c_list in list_of_lists if '0.0' not in c_list]
```

This will give all the lists with no `0.0` in them. If you want to skip the first two elements, then start from the third element, while checking

```
[c_list for c_list in list_of_lists if '0.0' not in c_list[2:]]
```

Comment: It should be `[2:]`, not `[3:]`. Lists are zero-indexed.

Comment: Except the zeros in his lists are `' 0.0'` and I'd not count on that particular spacing. `Tis better to use floats; at least 0.0 is guaranteed precise representation in IEEE-754.

Answer (score 1):

Noobie attempt. This is if you want to test if the value is 0.

Whereby l is your list in list.

```
for i in l:
    a=[]
    for j in i[2:]:
        if float(j)==0:
          break
    else:
        a.append(i)
```

Comment: +1 pretty good for a noob. You even got the `for / break / else` thing right. You missed the `for j in i[2:]:` thing but that was hidden in a comment, not in the OP question.

Comment: Nah, I missed that "skip the first two elements" myself at first. Be kind to yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are making this much harder than it needs to be.

1. List indices are often unnecessary in Python; use iteration instead.
2. Testing strings for equality to `'0.0'` is troublesome when your data has spaces `' 0.0'`
3. [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) are your friends.

Thus:

```
 def no_zeros(rows):
    """Takes a list of rows, prints each row if and only if it has no zeros."""
    for row in rows:
        # skip first two elements of row, per specification
        tests = [float(x) != 0 for x in row[2:]]
        if all(tests):
            print row
```

yields:

```
>>> no_zeros(A)
['10017.0', ' 43563.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', 
 ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', ' 0.106667', ' 0.0925', ' 0.09', ' 0.1', 
 ' 0.09', ' 0.1028']
```

Answer (score 0):

If A is your list of lists, filter(all, A)

Comment: Did you test it? `A` a-s an iterable is a list of length 6 (each of which is a list itself. A non-empty list is "trueish" so each of those lists in `A` will be true for `all` thus a list of all 6 lists will be returned.